# Private Route redirecting to 404 Error page instead of login page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Hi I am trying to make simple authentication using private routes and reducers, but my page is not redirecting to the login page but instead it opening a 404 error page. And the user can open any routes by changing the URL.

This is my App js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={MainPage} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/product/:id" component={ProductPage} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/cart" component={Cart} />
        <Route path="*" component={Error} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

This is my private route component,

```
export default function PrivateRoute({ children , ...rest }) {
  const loggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.Auth.loggedIn);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({location}) => {
        return loggedIn == true ? children : <Redirect to={{ pathname:'/login', state: {from : location}}}/>
      }}
    ></Route>
  );
}
```

Comment: Every other page is opening instead of the login page! and even though the login page opens, after entering the right credentials, it just opens the blank page instead of rendering the main component.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the routes matters.

Try putting your `Error` route at the bottom inside your `Switch`. The `Error` route seems to be matching the redirect before your `Login` has the chance to.

So try something like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={MainPage} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/product/:id" component={ProductPage} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path="/cart" component={Cart} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="*" component={Error} />
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Also I think you need to change `children` to `component` otherwise the redirect won't work.

So do something like this instead:

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  const loggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.Auth.loggedIn);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) => {
        return loggedIn == true ? (
          <Component />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: location } }} />
        );
      }}
    ></Route>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const loggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.Auth.loggedIn);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => (loggedIn ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/login',
          state: {
            from: props.location
          }
        }}
        />
      )
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: I implemented it but I can still access all the URL too

Comment: console log the loggedIn value and check once, this must work